# Shuffling a huge range of numbers using minimal storage

Tags: ruby, random, set, range, shuffle

I've got a very large range/set of numbers, `(1..1236401668096)`, that I would basically like to 'shuffle', i.e. randomly traverse **without revisiting** the same number. I will be running a Web service, and each time a request comes in it will increment a counter and pull the next 'shuffled' number from the range. The algorithm will have to accommodate for the server going offline, being able to restart traversal using the persisted value of the counter (something like how you can seed a pseudo-random number generator, and get the same pseudo-random number given the seed and which iteration you are on).

I'm wondering if such an algorithm exists or is feasible. I've seen the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), but the 1st step is to "Write down the numbers from 1 to N", which would take terabytes of storage for my entire range. Generating a pseudo-random number for each request might work for awhile, but as the database/tree gets full, collisions will become more common and could degrade performance (already a 0.08% chance of collision after 1 billion hits according to my calculation). Is there a more ideal solution for my scenario, or is this just a pipe dream?

The reason for the shuffling is that being able to correctly guess the next number in the sequence could lead to a minor DOS vulnerability in my app, but also because the presentation layer will look much nicer with a wider number distribution (I'd rather not go into details about exactly *what* the app does). At this point I'm considering just using a PRNG and dealing with collisions or shuffling range slices (starting with `(1..10000000).to_a.shuffle`, then, `(10000001, 20000000).to_a.shuffle`, etc. as each range's numbers start to run out).

Any mathemagicians out there have any better ideas/suggestions?

Comment: One option is to use a [linear feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register), although they are not cryptographically secure.

Comment: why not use a combination of a timestamp and a pseudo-random number or hash to reduce the likelihood of a collision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Concatenate a PRNG or LFSR sequence with `/dev/random` bits

There are several algorithms that can generate pseudo-random numbers with arbitrarily large and known periods. The two obvious candidates are the LCPRNG (LCG) and the LFSR, but there are more algorithms such as the Mersenne Twister.

The period of these generators can be easily constructed to fit your requirements and then you simply won't have collisions.

You could deal with the predictable behavior of PRNG's and LFSR's by adding 10, 20, or 30 bits of cryptographically hashed entropy from an interface like `/dev/random.` Because the deterministic part of your number is known to be unique it makes no difference if you ever repeat the actually random part of it.

Comment: I like the sound of this! I'll try creating an LCG with an m value of 1236401668096. I'm not too worried about it being strictly cryptographically secure, so I might just skip the /dev/random part. If no other great answers come along I'll mark this accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer? Break down into manageable chunks and shuffle them. You could divide the number range e.g. by their value modulo n. The list is constructive and quite small depending on n. Once a group is exhausted, you can use the next one.

For example if you choose an n of 1000, you create 1000 different groups. Pick a random number between 1 and 1000 (let's call this x) and shuffle the numbers whose value modulo 1000 equals x. Once you have exhausted that range, you can choose a new random number between 1 and 1000 (without x obviously) to get the next subset to shuffle. It shouldn't exactly be challenging  to keep track of which numbers of the 1..1000 range have already been used, so you'd just need a repeatable shuffle algorithm for the numbers in the subset (e.g. Fisher-Yates on their "indices").

Comment: Yep, I had considered this (end of 2nd-to-last paragraph); you might have missed it since my post is so verbose (I fail at the tl;dr thing).  Glad that it seems like a valid solution to someone else, as well!

Comment: @Abe: I kinda missed it, but I also suggested a less obvious way of partitioning than going in sequential slices.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best option is to use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid)/[UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid). They are made for this type of thing, and it shouldn't be hard to find an existing implementation to suit your needs.

While collisions are theoretically possible, they are extremely unlikely. To quote Wikipedia:

> The probability of one duplicate would be about 50% if every person on earth owns 600 million UUIDs

Comment: A UUID would certainly prevent collisions, but when I have to truncate it back into my smaller address space, I will once again have collisions I believe. Unfortunately, I am unable to expand my address space to reduce the likelihood of collisions. Thanks for your idea!